# Run without Debugging doesn't prompt to keep command line open

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, command-prompt, visual-studio-debugging

So I'm trying to run just a simple "Hello World" program on Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013, but the command prompt flashes for an instant before disappearing whenever I 'Start Debugging'. I Googled a bit, and found that "Run Without Debugging" is supposed to solve that issue by prompting the user to press a key before it exits. However, nothing at all changes when I Run Without Debugging.

I can't seem to find anything online about why this isn't working.

Comment: Is your "Hello World" program a Console application or a Windows application? Which did you intend for it to be? Do you *want* the Console window to show, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code.

> Console.ReadLine();

or

> Console.ReadKey();

These code preventing your program to end.

Comment: Thanks; I had found those before, and I know that they would work with my code. However, I still am confused about why the Run Without Debugging option doesn't work when it should.